# What are these file descriptors for?

Tags: node.js

Running this little script shows me that there is 12 opened descriptors when I run it. I know that 0,1,2 are stdin,stdout,sterr but what about the other 9 and why they're all opened and empty? Also, fd 9 seems to be a directory and I have no idea how to read it since fs.read returns `Error: EISDIR, illegal operation on a directory`.

```
fs = require('fs')

for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    console.log(i,fs.fstatSync(i).size)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at `/proc/<pid of node process>/fd/`. (If you are on linux)

```
0 -> /dev/pts/16
1 -> /dev/pts/16
2 -> /dev/pts/16
3 -> pipe:[6567721]
4 -> pipe:[6567721]
5 -> anon_inode:[eventpoll]
6 -> pipe:[6567722]
7 -> pipe:[6567722]
8 -> anon_inode:[eventfd]
9 -> /
```

So the directory of fd 9 is the root directory and the others are various forms of special file descriptors. I assume the two pairs of pipes are used by node internally to communicate between threads, as no other process is using them (checked with `lsof | grep 656772`)

Of course this does not tell you *why*, but it may be a first pointer.

Comment: Your listing of `/proc/<pid>/fd/` shows only 10 fd's and mine has 9. Is it possible to get any info on the unlisted 11 and 12 file descriptors?

Comment: Your code only yields 10 filedescriptors on my machine.

Comment: That's weird. Well, at least I would know what these first 9 fd's are. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> how to read it since fs.read returns Error: EISDIR, illegal operation on a directory.

Directories should be read using `fs.readdir`

http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_callback

Comment: Documentation says that it accepts directory path, not fd as a first argument. So, is it possible and safe to use file descriptor numbers with `fs.readdir`?

Comment: Ouch, I'm sorry, didn't read properly.

`EISDIR` error occurs if the `FLAGS` argument specified write access, and the file is a directory. 

So you need to either set flags as `read`, or catch errors like this and retry with any of ways above.